# Variable for Nth word until end

Tags: bash

Is there a variable for Nth word until end?

For example `./script One Two Three`:

`$1` is One and `$2-` is Two Three. Is this possible?

**Edit 1:** To explain in more detail I am running a command for example `./script 01-JAN-14 02-JAN-14 site` where `site` can be multiple words (but hasn't been up until this point so `$3` has sufficed in `script`).

**Edit 2:** I run `./script date1 date2 site` which runs an SQL query using the variables that are passed to it for example `WHERE date BETWEEN '$1' AND '$2'` and then `AND site = '${@: -3}'`. Is this correct, as it no longer works for single word `site` nor multiple words.

Comment: Just use quotes, please.

Comment: It is not a good practice to delete a question when somebody is helping you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404816/why-isnt-the-third-parameter-getting-passed-in-this-script In case you are done, just say it or edit the post. Otherwise, you are discouraging people to help you.

Answer (score 7):

it's possible in bash using e.g. `"${@: -3:1}"`, that is, slicing the arguments variable as if it were an array.

```
$ set -- one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
$ echo "$@"
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
$ n=-4
$ echo "${@:$n:1}"
seven
```

The space between `:` and the negative sign is necessary when using literal integers, but not when using a variable to expand to the offset (`"${@: -1:1}"` vs `"${@:$n:1}"`).

To get all the members of the arguments variable (or array) just leave off the second part of the expansion expression:

```
"${@: -3}" # third-to-last to last
```

Comment: +1.  Or if the sublist from 3rd before last to last is required, then simply `"${@: -3}"`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma yeah, I misread the question. Thanks for making me take a second look.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That definitely looks like what I need but for some reason I can't get it to work in my situation as expected. I added even more details to the question, do you see why it isn't working?

Comment: @user2656114 is your script bash or sh?

Comment: @kojiro Shall I update the question with more code? Sorry I didn't think more code was necessary when making the question.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't exactly a specific variable that means "rest" of arguments, but you can get that effect using `shift`. Contents of `script`:

```
echo $1
shift
echo $@
```

Test run:

```
$ ./script one two three
one
two three
```

Comment: +1 There is a way to get the trailing arguments (see kojiro's answer), but this is arguably a little cleaner if you don't mind modifying `$@` along the way, as well as being POSIX-compatible (`${var:offset:length}` is a `bash` extension).

Comment: @chepner thanks. Yes, kojiro's method is cool and I wasn't aware of that technique. Although to get "from argument 2 to the end" you have to first calculate the length of the argument list first to then determine how far back to go from the end.

Comment: From argument 2 to the end, you just use a positive offset: `${@:2}`.

Comment: @chepner Ah I see. Thanks. It wasn't on of the examples given in the answer. That's handy. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IFS` with `read`:

```
func() { IFS=' ' && read a b <<< $@; echo "<$a><$b>"; }
```

**TESTING:**

```
func One Two Three
<One><Two Three>

func One Two Three four five six seven eight nine ten
<One><Two Three four five six seven eight nine ten>
```

Comment: In general, this will fail for arguments that contain spaces.

Comment: Only if space is part of first argument i.e. "abc 123" but from OP's examples it doesn't look like that is the issue since OP is using a date in `DD-MON-YYYY` format

Comment: `b` also no longer distinguishes between the separate words, but lumps them all into a single string.

Comment: True but that is what OP wants as per me understanding before recent edits of the question.